Angular Keycloak : Window undefined
Hello I have some problems with Angular and Keycloak because of window.location.origin in this function but in the tutorial that I follow he did like that and it works, plz could you help me to solve it !!
The error is window undefined


function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080',
        realm: 'zetta',
        clientId: 'zetta-client'
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
//the problem is here
          window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html'
      }
    });
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    FormationsComponent,
   



  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule


  ],
  providers: [
    provideClientHydration(),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

This is the app.module.ts

i am not sure about your issue, show the exact error you get, but you may solve it with (window as any).location.origin or with declare var window;  at the top of your ts file

I copied the code from  the page angular keycloak to configure keycloak in angular but the error is just 'window undefined'. Thank you for your answer !

hope you could find a solution to your problem. usually errors are a little longer that just that and also shows the line of code and the file

the problem is server side rendering, you should disable it by replacing:
"ssr": {
  "entry": "server.ts"
}

by :
"ssr": false

in angular.json
